# fseek() - Access violation reading

Tags: c, file

I'm writing a method that compares file sizes (like any compare method).
Here is my method (I use `void *` as parameters because the other parts of the program require it):

```
int compareFileSize(void * p1, void * p2)
{
    int result;
    FILE * f1, *f2;
    f1 = (FILE *)p1;
    f2 = (FILE *)p2;
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);
    fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_END);
    result = ftell(f1) - ftell(f2);
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return result;
}
```

When it reaches the fseek() it crashes and says "Access violation reading" in the debugger.
Both files are fopened correctly before I call the method and are not `NULL`, I know this because if I fseek in the same way, just after the fopen, it works.

Why is this not working and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `void *`?

Comment: @EdHeal I use void * because I have a generic method that compares things from different types, integers, doubles, files and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess: you are writing a compare function for [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html), to which you pass an array of `FILE*` pointers:

```
FILE* arrfil[5] = { NULL };
arrfil[0] = stdout;
arrfil[1] = fopen("foo1","r");
arrfil[2] = fopen("foo2","r");
```

etc, later calling

```
qsort(arrfil, 5, sizeof(FILE*), compareFileSize);
```

Then, each `const void*` argument to the compare function is a pointer to a pointer, so you should code

```
int compareFileSize(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    FILE* f1 = *(FILE**)p1;
    FILE* f2 = *(FILE**)p2;
    if (f1 == f2) return 0;
    if (!f1) return 1;
    if (!f2) return -1;
    if (fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END)) return 1;
    if (fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_END)) return -1;
    result = ftell(f1) - ftell(f2);
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(f2, 0, SEEK_SET);
    eturn result;
}
```

Don't forget that user code never dereference a `FILE` (which is an opaque hidden `struct`); in other words, you *always* deal with `FILE*` *pointers* !

BTW, if you are coding for some POSIX system you might just use [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) and do

```
    struct stat st1 ={0}, st2={0};
    if (fstat(fileno(f1),&st1) return 1;
    if (fstat(fileno(f2),&st2) return -1;
    if (st1.st_size == st2.st_size) return 0;
    if (st1.st_size < st2.st_size) return -1;
    else return 1;
```

then you would use only two syscalls (and not four).

Comment: I make this mistake every time! Can't believe I didn't notice it before. Thank you very much.